# Robot Framework and IronPython

Tags: robotframework, ironpython, robotframework-ide

just a simple question. I have a Robot Framework which I am editing on RIDE and I have an Iron Python file, which includes a class and its methods. I import this ironpython file as a library and use its methods as keywords in my tests. However, RIDE seems to show that there is an error with importing that library.

A screenshot is displayed showing Vitality.py red.

[image]

Comment: There should be more information on `Tools->RIDE Log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out in the end it is because I hadn't install ride or robotframework for ironpython which is different to just python. You have to go through a different procedure for Ironpython of robotframework installation.